# How to check Node Configuration in Commerce Engine before Installing the SXC itself?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

For some reasons, I need to compare a Node configuration between one version of Sitecore Experience Commerce and another version.

Let's say I have only installed SXC 8.2.1 Update 2 and I haven't installed SXC 8.2.1 Update 3.

How can I check the Node Configuration of that 8.2.1 Update 3 just from the package before it is installed (e.g. in Sitecore.Commerce.8.2.1_U3_1.3.7)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the SDK that ships with the Product to achieve this. If you open up the `Customer.Sample.Solution.sln`

Then you could run the Engine project called `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine`

It wont run successfully as you don't have the DB's etc installed, but it should be enough to generate the NodeConfiguration output to disk

Comment: Thanks for your response, Rob.
I did that but didn't see any NodeConfigurationXXX.log. Could you please let me know the format of the output file (e.g. name and extension) and the directory path?

Comment: I've just attempted this locally and the NodeConfiguration file was generated to disk. It would be located at:
<<SDK_LOCATION>>\src\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine\wwwroot\logs

It will be called NodeConfiguration_Deployment01_<<GUID>>.log

I also pasted the contents into a PasteBin for you here: https://pastebin.com/svCGWQPq